# Can I use the same state.dir for multiple instances in Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My use case is to get the latest value for *any* key in a Kafka topic. For this, I am currently using GlobalStateStore.

The problem is that, if I have different `application.id` for each instance, a different state dir is being created.

What I would want is to reuse the existing state store dir across all instances to avoid duplicating the data.
This is because, all of my application instances run on the same machine, so there is no point of having different state directories.

**I have done the following:**

Use the same **application.id** and created 2 stream instances,
The 2 instances pointing to the same state.dir but the state store instances are different (java objects are different) *statestore1 and statestore2*

and then as a test I have done the following:

```
while(true)
{
 new Thread(()-> stateStore1.get(key)).start();
 new Thread(()-> stateStore2.get(key)).start();
}
```

and then I started producing values in the topic...

I have observed that all the state store instances (statestore1 and statestore2) are updating the same state store (i.e. same state.dir) (since that is the code)

I did not encounter any problems in the tests doing that. But.. I suppose that a write lock should be acquired before writing the data to the state.dir.
Now, if for some reason, statestore1 did not release the lock, then statestore2 will be going on waiting?

Is my above approach **safe** or are there any other ways?

**Update:**

The use-case is that there is some common data which I would want to share across different processes (different JVM instances). Since the data is common there is no need to have a global store for each process (since it would be redundant).

All processes should have the ability to read and write to that store because each process is independent of each other.
So if one process goes down, the other can do its work (store the latest value in the global store and get it when needed).

Answer (score 0):

If you run all on the same machine, and you want to share a global store, you should not use multiple instances, but multiple threads within an instance.

Global stores are designed to be replicated per instance, and this is exactly what you want to avoid.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have different applications running on different JVM instances, so it is not possible to have multi-threading there. What happens if I disable caching and ensure that I call the `put` only when the value is old. This way, all will see the same value and only one (the first) will be calling the `put`?

Comment: `different applications` -- do you mean different _instance_ of the same application? Or different _applications_ (ie, using different `application.id`)? `so it is not possible to have multi-threading there`: Why? It's a configuration `num.stream.threads` that you can set. Why can't you run a single JVM instead of multiple. --- Caching is not related to your question.

Comment: Basically, they are separate components (each have its own specific purpose) running in different JVM instances on the same machine, I don't have a problem giving the same `application.id` to all of them, though they run on different instances (processes).

Comment: The use-case is that all of them share a common information. Since they run on the same machine, I want to avoid creating a global store for each of those processes because it is redundant (since the data is same) and rather use the same one.

Comment: ok. So, you say that I can use **same** `application.id` for different instances (different JVM processes running on the same machine) and achieve what I want (i.e. write and read). In that case, since they are running on different processes, they have different `KafkaStreams` objects which have the same `application.id`

Comment: You should only use the same `application.id`, if it the same program. If it's different programs, you should use different `application.id`. You cannot share state across applications (not even instances), though, only over threads within the same `KafkaStreams` client. -- Also, global state is read-only anyway (it's written via its underlying topic).

Comment: I have updated my question with my requirement. (I think it is more of RocksDB handling multiple writes to the same state store from different processes).

Comment: My answer is still the same. Global stores can only be shared across thread within the same KafkaStreams instance. Also, you cannot actively write into a global store but only read from your application -- writes must go through the underlying input topic of the global store.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `state_dir` takes the parameter of the directory where a folder with the value of `application.id` will be created.

So, for example, if the `state_dir` is `C:\tmp` and the `application.id` is **test**, then the folder will be `C:\tmp\test`

So, if the `state_dir` is given to be `C:\tmp\test` rather than `C:\tmp` with the same `application.id` or even a different `application.id`, a new directory will be created in the `C:\tmp\test\` as `C:\tmp\test\test` or `C:\tmp\test\some_other_application_id`.

These doesn't conflict with each other. There will still be multiple global stores.

However, if the `state_dir` is given to be `C:\tmp` for both of the `KafkaStreams` instances, then there will be an exception stating

> Could not lock global state directory. This could happen if multiple
>   KafkaStreams instances are running on the same host using the same
>   state directory

For the use case of having a common place for all the instances, it is better to go with a database as sink to Kafka (either using the Kafka connect API or writing from streams to a database manually).

If the use case doesn't require complex SQL-like queries, then you can have your own `RocksDB` which will be writing to the same directory for all instances running on the same machine.

Kafka doesn't seem to support such a use-case out-of-the-box.